# Complete list of cities in timezones from NSTimeZone

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, nsdate

I'm using `+[NSTimeZone knownTimeZoneNames}` to get a complete list of timezones, but it doesn't include San Franscisco. Why is this happening? Is there a private API that provides the full list?

Answer (score 1):

You could do this: `NSLog(@"%@", [NSTimeZone abbreviationDictionary]);`
to see the timezone abbreviation.

Since San Francisco timezone falls under Pacific Standard Time (PST), it will be the same as 

`PST = "America/Los_Angeles";`

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

The list seems to include Los Angeles:

America/Los_Angeles

I don't think there's any difference in timezone between LA and SF (at least I never had to adjust my clock when flying between NorCal and SoCal). Why would SF be specifically included in that list?